# nutch on hadoop 2 (yarn) log files

Tags: nutch, hadoop-yarn

I am running nutch on a yarn cluster. I suspect that some of the crawl jobs timed out. I would like to see nutch log to varify this. On cloudera console, I only see log output about the yarn tasks, but nothing that is directly output by nutch.

Does anyone know where the nutch log would go?

Comment: How you solve your problem as I am also facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the logs in $NUTCH_HOME/runtime/local/logs?
Or the logs on console?  you can run the task by shell, and redirect the long to a file

Comment: No. this is in deploy mode, and only the apache-nutch-1.7.job jar is copied to the cluster node.